# Css hovering and overlapping elements problem

Tags: css, hover, transition, overlapping

Here's codepen link with button I'd like to use on my website:
https://codepen.io/nikolett_codes/pen/BMmOxO

here's HTML code:

```
<div class="phone cta">Call us</div>
<div class="phone number">(453) 416-4742</div>
```

And the problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKn2N.gif

Let's say "OP" is .cta original position, "NP" is .cta new position.
What is annoying is that if you hover over cta element and then move your cursor over it (at NP), the animation is not interrupted. Hover, when you hover over OP when .cta div is at NP (so basically hovering over .number div) it interrupts and goes back to OP.
How can i deal with it?

One way would be making transition when hovering over .number, but it's not possible because of z-index, so the animation will never start.
Another way would be to get .number position and apply eventlistener to this area, I suppose?
What is the best way to deal with this problem?

Comment: A proper [mre] of your issue belongs directly into your question, please do not just dump the whole thing onto an external platform.

Comment: _"Hover, when you hover over OP when .cta div is at NP (so basically hovering over .number div) it interrupts and goes back to OP."_ - of course it does, because now you are hovering over an element, that has nothing to do with triggering the effect in the first place. You should wrap _both_ into an additional element, and then apply the :hover on that.

Comment: @CBroe and to think that I already had wrapper with both elements for other reasons, yet failed to think about this hovering solution... Thank you so much, also thanks for feedback regarding my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this problem is to wrap both the .phone.cta and .phone.number divs inside a container div, and apply the :hover pseudo-class to the container instead of the .phone.cta div.

```
<div class="phone-container">
  <div class="phone cta">Call us</div>
  <div class="phone number">(453) 416-4742</div>
</div>
```

And add this to the css :

```
.phone-container {
      position: relative;
   }
    
   .number {
      z-index: 0;
      position: relative;
   }
   .phone-container:hover .cta {
      transform: translateX(-80%);
      transition: 1.2s;
   }
```